# Theorem for calculating the coordinate of standard basis vectors with respect to given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a theorem that tells how to calculate the coordinates of each of the standard vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to a given basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: An algorithm: Put the vectors of the basis, then put the 'standard basis' as columns. Do elimination until you get the reduced echelon form. In the position where the standard basis was you will get their coordinates.

Comment: Is this standard terminology? I'm familiar with "coordinates" referring to points or positions and "components" referring to the coefficients of a linear combination of basis vectors.

Comment: This is the terminology that I learned in class. I think its pretty general. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the matrix whose columns are the vectors of the given base.
If $e_i$ denote the $i$-th vector of the standard base, then $M^{-1}e_i$ is a vector whose components are the coordinates of $e_i$ respect to the given base.

Comment: So nicely defined. Would you be kind enough to explain why this algorithm is legitimate?

Comment: If $e_i=Mv$ with $v^T=(a,b,c)$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, and $M=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, with $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb R^3$, then $e_i=ax_1+bx_2+cx_3$.